# VBA union method not adding ranges

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find, union

I have the following code:

```
Dim alllrows As Range

Dim srchrng As Range
Set srchrng  = daylist.Find(What:=string, LookIn:=xlValues)
Dim startaddr As String
startaddr = srchrng.Address


Do        
    If alllrows  Is Nothing Then
        Set alllrows = srchrng          
    Else
        Set alllrows = Union(alllrows , srchrng )            
    End If
    Set srchrng = daylist.FindNext(srchrng )

    If srchrng Is Nothing Or startaddr = srchrng .Address Then
        GoTo Done
    End If
Loop
```

When I debug, `alllrows.Rows.Count` always stays at 1. I see the code hitting the union statement, but the count always stays one and the value in the Range also does not change. The value always shows as the first entry that was added to  `alllrows`.

Comment: what's your actual problem? I mean, what do you need `alllrows.Rows.Count` for?

Comment: `Rows.Count` only returns the number of rows for the first *area* in a range. `Debug.Print allrows.Address`?

Comment: @BigBen, that's what I was pointing at...

Comment: or use `Debug.Print alllrows.Areas.Count` to see how many discontinuous ranges have been added to `alllRows`

Comment: Thanks, using `allrows.Address` and `alllrows.Areas.Count`, I am able to see all the data now.